# angular $state.reload not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state set up for logging out a user. I have it set up like this:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: '/account/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/account/login/login.tpl.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    }).state('logout', {
        url: '/account/logout',
        resolve: {
            logout: ['$state', 'AccountService', function ($state, account) {
                console.log('start logging out');
                account.logout();
                console.log('logging out');
                console.log($state);
                $state.go('login');
                console.log('logged out');
            }]
        }
    });
}])
```

When I navigate to the **logout** state all the console.logs are hit, but the $state does not change.
I have tried several things:

```
$state.go('login', {}, { reload: true });
```

and

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });
```

and

```
$state.reload();
```

but no matter which one I try, I can not get the $state to change to the correct state.

Does anyone know why?

**Update**

so I have changed my state to this:

```
}).state('logout', {
    url: "/account/logout",
    templateUrl: '/app/account/logout.tpl.html', // If we don't have a template then the state will not change in our resolve
    resolve: {
        logout: ['$state', 'AccountService', function ($state, account) {
            account.logout();
            console.log('logging out');
            $state.go('login');
        }]
    }
});
```

and it still isn't going to the login screen. The console is logging the logging out bit and if I refresh the page I am actually logged out, so that code is working fine. It doesn't doesn't redirect...

Answer (score 0):

There is no template in the `logout` state so it **IS** changing the state but there's no visual change so it keeps showing the same view. Verify that the *url* is changing if you want to be 110% sure that the state is changing.

Comment: If I set the url to '/account/login' would I need to specify a template?

Comment: That's correct, but I think it would brake the purpose of the `logout` state, I would suggest adding a `$state.go('login')` **after** calling the `account.logout()` function.

Comment: I have updated the question, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @r3plica I'm not particularly familiar with the `resolve`, have you tried doing it through a controller? pass it a function as controller to the state like `state('logout', {url: '/logout', controller: function() {//put here the code you have in the resolve}});`

Comment: yeah I could do it that way, there would be no issues, but I wanted to do it in a clean way :) it doesn't matter, I will figure it out and post it here if I manage